# PHP7 variable into URL

Tags: php, variables, url, path

How can I get the variable into the URL in php7 instead of request parameters i would take the variable into the URL as path part.

How can I get the path part?

```
Example
localhost/myfolder/{my_var}/
```

i want handle the $my_var variable

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking how to put a variable's value into a URL, or put part of the URL into a variable?

Comment: @barmar i agree, its confusing :-)

Answer (score 0):

First you need .htaccess with the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

then in your index.php, you can do the following

```
$path_info = !empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '');
$path_array = explode('/', $path_info);
$my_var = $path_array[1];
echo $my_var;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way for do that if i can't touch htaccess?

Comment: The thing is, if you don't use htaccess, the server will see the ~/{my_var}/ as a folder  and report Error 404.